# How can I "convert" 2 processes to a parent-child process?

Tags: c, parent-child

So I've got this great code for a C example of a deadlock by [Ali Hasan Ahmed Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12460195/ali-hasan-ahmed-khan) previously. I was just thinking about converting it to a parent-child process, so somehow making funcA the parent, then forking funcB. When I used the fork command, I was met with an error in main, saying funcB is non existent. Can this be converted? The full code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

#define PERMS 0660

int semId;

int initSem(int semId, int semNum, int initValue) {
    return semctl(semId, semNum, SETVAL, initValue);
}

// Try to take a resource, wait if not available
int P(int semId, int semNum) {
    struct sembuf operationList[1];
    operationList[0].sem_num = semNum;
    operationList[0].sem_op = -1;
    operationList[0].sem_flg = 0;
    return semop(semId, operationList, 1);
}

// Release a resource
int V(int semId, int semNum) {
    struct sembuf operationList[1];
    operationList[0].sem_num = semNum;
    operationList[0].sem_op = 1;
    operationList[0].sem_flg = 0;

    return semop(semId, operationList, 1);
}

void* funcA(void* nothing) {
    printf("Thread A try to lock 0...\n");
    P(semId, 0);        // Take resource/semaphore 0     of semID
    printf("Thread A locked 0.\n");

    usleep(50*1000);  // Wait 50 ms

    printf("Thread A try to lock 1...\n");
    P(semId, 1);        // Take resource/semaphore 1 of semID
    printf("Thread A locked 1.\n");

    V(semId, 0);        // Release resource/semaphore 0 of semID
    V(semId, 1);        // Release resource/semaphore 1 of semID
    return NULL;
}

void* funcB(void* nothing) {
    printf("Thread B try to lock 1...\n");
    P(semId, 1);
    printf("Thread B locked 1.\n");

    usleep(5*1000);

    printf("Thread B try to lock 0...\n");
    P(semId, 0);
    printf("Thread B locked 0.\n");

    V(semId, 0);
    V(semId, 1);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;

    // ftok generates a key based on the program name and a char value
semId = semget(ftok(argv[0], 'A'), 2, IPC_CREAT | PERMS);

initSem(semId, 0, 1);
initSem(semId, 1, 1);

pthread_t thread[2];

pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, funcA, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread[1], NULL, funcB, NULL);

for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
}
printf("This is not printed in case of deadlock\n");
semctl(semId, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
semctl(semId, 1, IPC_RMID, 0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot find a `fork()` in your program.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I deleted it because of the error. I tried 2 methods, one was to include a fork() and funcB in the body of funcA, the other was to only have a fork() and funcB in the body of funcA.

Comment: Looks like you can not. Otherwise a malicious process can make any process its child process and do whatever it wants